# Java ArrayList initialization

Tags: java, arraylist, function-parameter

I've been trying to understand the following code that uses Depth-First-Search (DFS) to print out all unique combinations of length k comprising of numbers [1..n]

Please see the line commented "doubt" in the private dfs function

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> combine(int n, int k) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    if (n <= 0 || n < k)
        return result;
    ArrayList<Integer> item = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    dfs(n, k, 1, item, result); 
    return result;
}

private void dfs(int n, int k, int start, ArrayList<Integer> item,
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> res) {
    if (item.size() == k) {
        res.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(item)); /*doubt*/
        return;
    }

    for (int i = start; i <= n; i++) {
        item.add(i);
        dfs(n, k, i + 1, item, res);
        item.remove(item.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

If I change it to res.add(item) it returns result as list of null lists. ListObject.add(E e) is a perfectly valid function, why doesn't it work here?

Comment: Because you're modifying the same list pointed by `item` in for loop. That will also modify the list for the reference stored in `res` list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your question concerns these two alternatives:

```
// works
res.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(item));

// won't work, results in empty lists
res.add(item);
```

The purpose of `new ArrayList<Integer>(item)` is to create a new list with the same content as the original, effectively cloning the original.

If you don't clone the original, it will stay empty. The first time `dfs` is called, `item` is empty, and then look at this loop:

```
for (int i = start; i <= n; i++) {
    item.add(i);
    dfs(n, k, i + 1, item, res);
    item.remove(item.size() - 1);
}
```

Every element added to `item` will be later removed. This is why you end up with empty lists without the cloning step. Without cloning, not only you get a list of empty lists, all of the empty lists are actually the same original `ArrayList` that you created in `combine`, before the first call to `dfs`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `item.remove(item.size() - 1);` is modifying the same list that you just added to your list of results. So it always ends up removing all the items. The solution you have is actually copying the list of items and storing them in your result list. No one has a reference to that list so it doesn't get modified.